# Is there any assembly language debugger for windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c, assembly, editor

I have a 64 bit m/c having windows 7.I want to start assembly language programming.What editor and compiler should I use.Please mention the sites also from where I can download these softwares.I typed debug in command prompt but it gave me this message This version of C:\Windows\system32\debug.exe is not compatible with the version
 of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whet
her you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then con
tact the software publisher.
How can I view the contents of my memory without debug

Comment: [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).

Comment: [This](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D) shows you how to set up Visual Studio with x64 assembly & debugging tools. It then going into a really good full fledged assembly tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf). It's a handy guide, and I'm pretty sure Visual Studio would include a debugger.

Though honestly, if I were you, I'd start learning x86 under Linux, using maybe nasm as an assembler and gdb as a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Visual Studio express (free version). It is possible to include .asm files in your project, and the visual debugger that comes with Visual Studio is frankly one of the best I've worked with.

An other advantage for people who want to start Intel assembler is that you can start with inline assembler in one integrated environment, which means that you don't have to go into the little deatails of program structure (COM vs. EXE vs. DLL vs. ...), function calls and stack management right away. You can first write function contents (even within the frame of the Common Object Model). Afterward you can bit by bit convert to a full fledged assembler application.

Kind regards,
PF